# Combine 2 queries in one

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to combine 2 queries in one. I would like to draw a letter from last_name, and look for countriers which start with that letter. My query gives me more than one letter, and I don't know why.

```
    SELECT CONCAT(LOWER(SUBSTR(country, 1, LENGTH(country) - 1)), 
           UPPER(substr(country, -1))) AS Kraj,
           COUNT(C.country_id) AS ilosc
FROM city AS C
JOIN country AS CO ON C.country_id = CO.country_id
WHERE country LIKE
    (SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(last_name, 1), '%')
     FROM actor
     ORDER BY RAND()
     LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY C.country_id
HAVING COUNT(C.country_id) > 1;
```

Comment: first change it to INNER_JOIN will be much readable for you :
JOIN country AS CO ON C.country_id = CO.country_id

second :
you are pulling from a tables we don't see the data. if you want to retrieve only one result for the example you take consider using DISTINCT

Comment: Database came from: http://mysql-tools.com/downloads/mysql-databases/4-sakila-db.html

Answer (score 0):

first change it to INNER_JOIN will be much readable for you : JOIN country AS CO ON C.country_id = CO.country_id second : you are pulling from a tables we don't see the data. if you want to retrieve only one result for the example you take consider using DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(LOWER(SUBSTR(country, 1, LENGTH(country) - 1)), 
       UPPER(substr(country, -1))) AS Kraj,
       COUNT(C.country_id) AS ilosc
FROM city AS C
INNER JOIN country AS CO ON C.country_id = CO.country_id
WHERE country LIKE
    (SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(last_name, 1), '%')
     FROM actor
     ORDER BY RAND()
     LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY C.country_id
HAVING COUNT(C.country_id) > 1;
```

Comment: it doesn't matter if I am using join, or inner join, it is the same

Comment: yes but its make it more easier to read and understand.
you right. i mention its the same :)

Answer (score 0):

For each country the DBMS evaluates the criteria in the `WHERE` clause, thus execting the subquery again and again and resulting in various letters instead of just one.

Use a `CROSS JOIN` to provide one random letter instead.

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(LOWER(SUBSTR(country, 1, LENGTH(country) - 1)), UPPER(substr(country, -1))) AS Kraj,
  COUNT(C.country_id) AS ilosc
FROM city AS C
JOIN country AS CO ON C.country_id = CO.country_id
CROSS JOIN 
(
  SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(last_name, 1), '%') AS letter
  FROM actor
  ORDER BY RAND()
  LIMIT 1
) the_one
WHERE country LIKE the_one.letter
GROUP BY C.country_id
HAVING COUNT(C.country_id) > 1;
```